# validates_presence_of if condition on rails 3.2 and mongoid + simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I want validate presence of these 2 attributes `:shipping_cost` and `:shipping_cost_anywhere` if the attribute `:shipping` is equal to `true`. and If

I have this in my model but not working fine for me:

```
validates_presence_of :shipping_cost, :shipping_cost_anywhere, :allow_blank => "true" if :shipping == "true"
```

this is my :shipping attribute:

```
field :shipping, :type => Boolean, :default => "false"
```

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Edited.

**I'm using mongoid and simple_form gems**

Comment: Please be more specific on how it is not working fine for you. That makes it easier to guess what you try to express. :)

Comment: Thank you, the fields `:shipping_cost` and `:shipping_cost_anywhere` are not validated if I set to true the field `:shipping`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix for me to this question is the next code:

```
validates :shipping_cost, :shipping_cost_anywhere, :presence => true, :if => :shipping?
```

Thank you to all for your help but any answer has worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 12):

```
validates_presence_of :shipping_costs_anywhere, :if => :should_be_filled_in?

def should_be_filled_in?
  shipping_costs_anywhere == "value"
end
```

The method will return true or false when it's called in the statement.
No need to put colon in front of shipping_costs_anywhere.

Comment: I get with this method `undefined method should_be_filled_in? for #<Item:0xfd43028>`

Comment: the method should be should_be_filled_in? rather than should_be_filled_in

Comment: Thank you I have checked with this but it does not works fine for me. Thank you!

Comment: When using :should_be_filled_in? it checks for 2 values either true or false make sure to assign this to :shipping_costs_anywhere in your form. when returned true you want to ask yourself :shipping_costs_anywhere == true. if you want to check if it is filled in blank you might want to as :shipping_costs_anywhere != ""

Comment: Do you think or did you check? if so I'll have to update the answer

Comment: conditional validations require a symbol for the method

Comment: It was exactly as I suspected.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled across this today and thought I'd freshen the answer. As others mentioned, you can put the logic in a function. However, you can also just throw it in a proc.

```
validates_presence_of :shipping_costs_anywhere, :if => Proc.new { |o|
  o.shipping_costs_anywhere == "value"}
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

Answer (score 4):

The `validates` is now preferred over `validates_presences_of` etc. As hyperjas mentioned you can do this:

```
validates :shipping_cost,
  :shipping_cost_anywhere,
  :presence => true, :if => :shipping?
```

However, that conditionalizes the entire validation for both `:shipping_cost` and `:shipping_cost_anywhere`. For better maintainability, I prefer a separate `validate` declaration for each attribute.

More importantly, you will likely run into situations where you have multiple validations with different conditions (like one for presence and another for length, format or value). You can do that like this:

```
validates :shipping_cost,
  presence: { if: :shipping? },
  numericality: { greater_than: 100, if: :heavy? }
```

You can also let rails evaluate a ruby string.

```
validates :shipping_cost,
  presence: { if: "shipping?" },
  numericality: { greater_than: 100, if: "shipping? and heavy?" }
```

And finally, optionally add separate custom messages:

```
validates :shipping_cost,
  presence: { if: "shipping?", message: 'You forgot the shipping cost.' },
  numericality: { greater_than: 100, if: "shipping? and heavy?", message: 'Shipping heavy items is $100 minimum.' }
```

And so on. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it, but I think the syntax is more like:

```
validates_presence_of :shipping_cost, :shipping_cost_anywhere, :allow_blank => "true", :if => "shipping.nil?"
```

See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation

Comment: You can also define a method as the others suggest. Incidentally, I also noticed that the Rails guide mentions that the presence validator ignores the :allow_blank option, but if that is working for you I won't argue.

Comment: It's not clear to me based on your question and later comment if you want to validate when shipping is true, or when it is *not* true. To validate when shipping is true, use `:unless`. If you want to validate when shipping is *not* true, use `:if`.

Comment: Thank you the problem is that if I remove `:allow_blank => "true"` always validate the fields, the condition is ignored, but If I add the `:allow_blank => "true"` never validate the form the condition is ignored...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code working for me.Call method on if condition rather than comparing

```
 validates :prefix, :allow_blank => true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => true } ,:if => :trunk_group_is_originating?


        def trunk_group_is_originating?
          if self.direction == "originating"
            true
          else
            false
          end
        end
```

Hope it helps you.......