# Mongoid : The Validation "validates_uniqueness_of" is only triggered when the specific field changes

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a unique constraint defined using a condition. But the following test does not pass :

```
class Dummy
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String
  field :status, :type => Boolean

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, if: :status
end


describe "UniquenessValidator" do
  let!(:d1) { Dummy.create!(name: 'NAME_1', status: true) }
  let!(:d2) { Dummy.create!(name: 'NAME_1', status: false) }

  it "should raise an error" do
    expect {
      d2.status = true
      d2.save!
    }.to raise_error
  end
end
```

Since `name_changed?` is false, no validation seems to happen and therefore the uniqueness condition is not checked.

Is it a bug ? Or have I forgotten something ? I guess it's an optimization to avoid to run the validation each time the element is modified.

In that case what is the good way to trigger the validation when the status is changed ?

Thanks!

Comment: [The mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html) state that "Mongoid behaves slightly different to Active Record when using #valid? on already persisted data. Active Record's #valid? will run all validations whereas Mongoid's #valid? will only run validations on documents that are in memory as an optimization." Maybe that helps.

Comment: @p11y : indeed (https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/3.1.0-stable/lib/mongoid/validations/uniqueness.rb#L289). hummm...

Comment: Dirty Workaround : Override in the Model

def attribute_changed?(attr)
  if attr == 'name' and self.status_changed?
    true
  else
    super
  end
end

Comment: Did you try using `if: :status?` instead of `if: :status` ? More on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501401/validates-presence-of-if-condition-on-rails-3-2-and-mongoid-simple-form

Comment: Wow @PatrickOscity thanks for bringing that to our attention. That "optimization" is absurd. I might move off Mongoid in future projects for that reason alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you case is a edge case, I would advice you to create your own validator class for this, something like this should work:

```
class NameUniquenessValidator < Mongoid::Validatable::UniquenessValidator
private
  def validation_required?(document, attribute)
    return true "name" == attribute.to_s
    super
  end
end

class Dummy
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String
  field :status, :type => Boolean

  validates_with(NameUniquenessValidator, :name, if: :status)
end
```

Comment: FYI, I have created a github issue : https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3343

Comment: Cool.. i will take a look into it too.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the status field so, you need to validate this field. You can do something like this:

```
class Dummy
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String
  field :status, :type => Boolean

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, if: :status
  validates_uniqueness_of :status, scope: :name, if: :status
end
```

I don't know if you can force mongoid to validate all fields when you update a single field.

Comment: It seems like a step in the right direction, but validating that the status is unique is unfortunately not a viable solution in the general case, i.e. when the dependent attribute is not unique.

Comment: Also, you are missing a colon in the last line before `status`. Edited.

Comment: Yeah, this is a solution for this case. For general case you will need to create custom validation for status field depending of status properties. Thanks for the correction.